# How to get bash's `cat` program to handle [No such file or directory] edge cases?

Tags: bash, try-catch, glob, cat

With `mv` or `rm` I would use the `-f` flag but I'm sure how to handle this for `cat`.

Is there a way to do this? An alternative that can handle this edge case? or a single line try/except that can handle this edge case?

e.g.,

```
cat path/to/potential_files/*.fa > output.fa

cat: 'path/to/potential_files/*.fa': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Redirect stderr to /dev/null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a `try ... catch ...` with

```
cat file 2>/dev/null ||
  { 
    echo 'Catch block, only reached when $? -ne 0'
    echo 'Another catch statement'
  }
# Or oneliner (note the spaces around the curly braces and the semicolons)
cat file 2>/dev/null || { echo 'Something '; echo 'else'; }
```

Comment: I ended up adapting your answer a bit. Thank you. `cat filepath 2>/dev/null || > filepath`

Answer (score 1):

You can use globbing to iterate through all the files that match **.fa** and append to the outout file using **>>**:

```
for file in "$YOUR_PATH/*.fa"; do
    cat "$file" >> outout_file.txt
done
```

Comment: I still get the same error...hmmm. Here's an example (first showing there's no *.fa) ```(base) -bash-4.2$ ls *.fa
ls: cannot access '*.fa': No such file or directory
(base) -bash-4.2$ for FP in "*.fa"; do cat $FP >> test.txt; done
cat: '*.fa': No such file or directory```

Comment: This error might indicate that you do not have write permission to that path, only read.